# Как перестроить запрос, чтобы ключи были даже когда данные отсутствуют?

Tags: запрос, mysql

Есть такой запрос

```
SELECT SUM(`total`) AS `sum`,CONCAT_WS('-',year(FROM_UNIXTIME(`unix`)),DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(`unix`),'%m')) AS `key` FROM `shop_orders` WHERE `status` NOT IN (1,6) AND `unix` BETWEEN ".(int)$start." AND ".(int)$end." GROUP BY `key`
```

Возвращает он массив данных формата **[2012-08] => 4252.00**
В переменных `$start` и `$end` unix-даты начала августа 2011 и конца августа 2012 соответственно. Если в БД нет записей с датой какого-нибудь месяца, то ключ с этой датой естественно отсутствует, это логично.

Вопрос: возможно ли перестроить запрос таким образом, чтоб ключи были в любом случае, а если данные отсутствуют, то значение было 0?

Пример (при отсутствии данных в БД за апрель и июнь):

```
[2012-04] => 0
[2012-05] => 152.00
[2012-06] => 0
[2012-07] => 5721.00
[2012-08] => 4252.00
```

Comment: проверяйте год, if(YEAR(dt)>0,dt,'0') as 'god'

Comment: @Vfvtnjd, а пример можно?

И мне не нужно год заменять на 0, мне нужно чтоб формат [год-месяц] сохранялся в искомом промежутке, даже если записи в БД на данный месяц отсутствуют

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь ф-цией [IFNULL()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull)

Comment: А пример на основе моего запроса?
Что такое IFNULL я знаю, но прикрутить его к запросу правильным образом мне не удалось

Comment: Запрос:

    SELECT IFNULL(SUM(`total`),0) AS `sum`,
    CONCAT_WS('-',year(FROM_UNIXTIME(`unix`)),DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(`unix`),'%m')) AS `key` 
    FROM `shop_orders` 
    WHERE `status` NOT IN (1,6) 
    AND `unix` BETWEEN ".(int)$start." 
    AND ".(int)$end." 
    GROUP BY `key`

Comment: не, так не пойде, пробовал уже. в этом случае запрос вставлает 0 если SUM(total)=0 и запись с нужной датой есть в БД, а мне нужно чтоб он на выходе давал данные даже если дата отсутствует.

Comment: Чтобы запрос возвращал дата там должна быть - хотябы пустая, иначе селект с воздуха сам не нарисует.

Пустые даты, нужно проверять и добивать на уровне кода уже.

Comment: @Ёхарный Бабай, вот я про то и спрашивал, можно ли создавать данные взамен отсутствующих

Comment: Если в таблице нет какой либо даты, то и в результатах запроса она не появится.
Необходимо либо добавить даты в таблицу (без значений), либо подставлять из скрипта (например в цикле), как уже было сказано @Ёхарный Бабай и @Vfvtnjd.

Comment: Создать вспомогательную таблицу с полным набором нужных месяцев и LEFT (или RIGHT) JOIN с Вашим запросом.